# Frame or iframe to refresh only part of a page

Tags: iframe, frames, frameset

I have an objective to display a list (dynamic ASP page) a video and another list (dynamic ASP page) the first list needs to refresh every five seconds.  Using the meta refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=terminal.asp?x=<%= runningInterval %>" />
```

is no good because everytime the single page refreshed the video re-starts/reloads.  So I am thinking frames, or should it be iframes???

Will I be able to build a frames/ iframes version of this where one of the pages that feeds the first frame section has the meta refresh. SO only this section refreshes, will this work???  Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

You could use iframes, and use a Javascript reload based on a timer.

```
timer = setTimeout(reloadFrame(document.getElementById('frameEl'), 3000), 3000);

function reloadFrame(frameEl, timeout){
    frameEl.location.reload();

    if(timeout != NULL){
        setTimeout(reloadFrame(frameEl, 3000), 3000);
    }
}
```